# lmer - interpreting fixed effects correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, lme4-nlme

I fitted four mixed linear models for 4 DVs, and 5 IVs in each of these models as fixed effects (there is a random effect as well). These 5 IVs are "time" (weeks from 1-12, 12 levels), and 4 measures of linguistic characteristics (LCs) (continuous variables). What I was trying to do is to introduce an interaction effect between time and 4 LCs, however, those models yielded worse fit, so I decided not to include interaction.

However, correlation matrix of fixed effects shows that time is not correlated with those LCs for all four models. That is, for each of them, results show that weeks are not correlated with LCs.

How can I interpret those results? Can I conclude that linguistic characteristics do not change over time (at least for those 12 weeks analyzed)? I know that this is not such a robust technique to draw such a conclusion, but is it valid at all?

Comment: Did you treat time as a continuous variable, or as a factor?  Saying it had "12 levels" makes it sound like a factor, but that's a lot of levels (you end up with 11 predictors, when you probably just want one).

Comment: Can you explain what "DVs" and "IVs" are?